# Nextcloud container after move

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nextcloud, openmediavault

I have server, which is hp t620 with 64gb ssd inside and two 1tb hdd disk in the cover connected by USB 3.0 and configured in RAID 1 (cover has option to configured RAID 1, 0 and JBOD). HDD disk are mounted under `/srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-9eac4f7c-81d6-48a7-9a4a-c8f20ceba7b5`
It operates under `OMV 5.10`.
I installed the docker by OMV web GUI in `/srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-9eac4f7c-81d6-48a7-9a4a-c8f20ceba7b5/dane_aplikacji/docker`. I run on the docker the nextcloud server app from the docker-compose file:

```
version: '3' 

services:
  proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine
    labels:
      - "com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy=true"
    container_name: nextcloud-proxy
    networks:
      - nextcloud_network
    ports:
      - 88:80
      - 444:443
    volumes:
      - ./proxy/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d:rw
      - ./proxy/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d:rw
      - ./proxy/html:/usr/share/nginx/html:rw
      - ./proxy/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_PROTO=https
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=444
    restart: unless-stopped
  
  letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    container_name: nextcloud-letsencrypt
    depends_on:
      - proxy
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    networks:
      - nextcloud_network
    environment:
      - PUID=998 #change PUID if needed
      - PGID=100  #change PGID if needed
      - TZ=Europe/Warsaw # change Time Zone if needed
      - URL=myurl.duckdns.org
      - SUBDOMAINS=www
      - VALIDATION=https
      - EMAIL=myaccount@gmail.com
    volumes:
      - ./proxy/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
      - ./proxy/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d:rw
      - ./proxy/html:/usr/share/nginx/html:rw
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    restart: unless-stopped

  db:
    image: mariadb
    command: --skip-innodb-read-only-compressed
    container_name: nextcloud-mariadb
    networks:
      - nextcloud_network
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD= SUPER_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=SUPER_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_HOST=db
    restart: unless-stopped
  
  app:
    image: nextcloud:latest #ghcr.io/linuxserver/nextcloud
    container_name: nextcloud-app
    hostname: myurl.duckdns.org
    networks:
      - nextcloud_network
    depends_on:
      - letsencrypt
      - proxy
      - db
    volumes:
      - nextcloud:/var/www/html:z
      - ./app/config:/var/www/html/config
      - ./app/custom_apps:/var/www/html/custom_apps
      - /srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-9eac4f7c-81d6-48a7-9a4a-c8f20ceba7b5/nextcloud:/var/www/html/data
      - ./app/themes:/var/www/html/themes
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro

    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Warsaw
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=myurl.duckdns.org
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=myurl.duckdns.org:444
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=myaccount@gmail.com
      - PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT=20G
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=SUPER_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=SUPER_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_HOST=db
      - NEXTCLOUD_HOSTNAME=myurl.duckdns.org
    restart: unless-stopped

  news-updater: 
    image: kr3ssh/nextcloud-news-updater
    environment:
      - INTERVAL=60
      - NEXTCLOUD_URL=http://myurl.duckdns.org:88
      - NEXTCLOUD_ADMIN_USER=PAN_ADMIN
      - NEXTCLOUD_ADMIN_PASSWORD=SUPER_PASSWORD
    restart: always       

volumes:
  nextcloud:
  db:

networks:
  nextcloud_network:
```

When I started to use the server i have only 16gb ssd inside and I had have docker files on the `/srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-9eac4f7c-81d6-48a7-9a4a-c8f20ceba7b5/dane_aplikacji/docker` but  recently I installed 64gb ssd. I have taken OS img and installed it on the 64gb disk by rufus and expand partition. Docker and nextcloud work without no problem. Next I have copied docker file from `/srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-9eac4f7c-81d6-48a7-9a4a-c8f20ceba7b5/dane_aplikacji/docker` to `/var/lib.docker` and run docker from there by OMV web GUI. It was bad idea because nextcloud container hasn't worked. On the web page I only see:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator if this error reappears multiple times, please include the technical details below in your report.
More details can be found in the server log.
```

In the nextcloud log file I see:

```
[Sat Jan 15 15:14:11.109982 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.51 (Debian) PHP/8.0.14 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Jan 15 15:14:11.110121 2022] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
ITS.MYI.P - - [15/Jan/2022:15:14:12 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 717 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/ITS.MYI.P Safari/537.36 Edg/ITS.MYI.P"
ITS.MYI.P - admin [15/Jan/2022:15:14:38 +0100] "GET /index.php/apps/news/api/v1-2/cleanup/before-update HTTP/1.1" 500 717 "-" "Python-urllib/3.7"
```

In the nginx log file I see:

```
Lines
100
Actions   
      
nginx.1     | 2022/01/15 15:14:08 [notice] 24#24: start worker processes
nginx.1     | 2022/01/15 15:14:08 [notice] 24#24: start worker process 30
nginx.1     | 2022/01/15 15:14:08 [notice] 24#24: start worker process 31
nginx.1     | 2022/01/15 15:14:08 [notice] 24#24: start worker process 32
nginx.1     | 2022/01/15 15:14:08 [notice] 24#24: start worker process 33
dockergen.1 | 2022/01/15 15:14:08 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
dockergen.1 | 2022/01/15 15:14:08 Watching docker events
dockergen.1 | 2022/01/15 15:14:08 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
nginx.1     | myurl.duckdns.org ITS.MYI.P - admin [15/Jan/2022:15:14:08 +0100] "GET /index.php/apps/news/api/v1-2/cleanup/before-update HTTP/1.1" 503 190 "-" "Python-urllib/3.7" "-"
dockergen.1 | 2022/01/15 15:14:09 Received event start for container 70f8ad9b1266
dockergen.1 | 2022/01/15 15:14:09 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
nginx.1     | myurl.duckdns.org ITS.MYI.P - - [15/Jan/2022:15:14:09 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 592 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/ITS.MYI.P Safari/537.36 Edg/ITS.MYI.P" "-"
dockergen.1 | 2022/01/15 15:14:10 Received event start for container 94b2d83900f4
dockergen.1 | 2022/01/15 15:14:10 Generated '/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf' from 10 containers
dockergen.1 | 2022/01/15 15:14:10 Running 'nginx -s reload'
nginx.1     | 2022/01/15 15:14:10 [notice] 24#24: signal 1 (SIGHUP) received from 37, reconfiguring
nginx.1     | 2022/01/15 15:14:10 [notice] 24#24: reconfiguring
nginx.1     | 2022/01/15 15:14:10 [notice] 24#24: using the "epoll" event method
nginx.1     | 2022/01/15 15:14:10 [notice] 24#24: start worker processes
nginx.1     | 2022/01/15 15:14:10 [notice] 24#24: start worker process 38
nginx.1     | 2022/01/15 15:14:10 [notice] 24#24: start worker process 39
nginx.1     | 2022/01/15 15:14:10 [notice] 24#24: start worker process 40
nginx.1     | 2022/01/15 15:14:10 [notice] 24#24: start worker process 41
nginx.1     | 2022/01/15 15:14:10 [notice] 30#30: gracefully shutting down
nginx.1     | 2022/01/15 15:14:10 [notice] 31#31: gracefully shutting down
nginx.1     | 2022/01/15 15:14:10 [notice] 30#30: exiting
nginx.1     | 2022/01/15 15:14:10 [notice] 32#32: gracefully shutting down
nginx.1     | 2022/01/15 15:14:10 [notice] 32#32: exiting
nginx.1     | 2022/01/15 15:14:10 [notice] 30#30: exit
nginx.1     | 2022/01/15 15:14:10 [notice] 32#32: exit
nginx.1     | 2022/01/15 15:14:10 [notice] 33#33: gracefully shutting down
nginx.1     | 2022/01/15 15:14:10 [notice] 33#33: exiting
nginx.1     | 2022/01/15 15:14:10 [notice] 33#33: exit
nginx.1     | 2022/01/15 15:14:10 [notice] 24#24: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 33
nginx.1     | 2022/01/15 15:14:10 [notice] 24#24: worker process 33 exited with code 0
nginx.1     | 2022/01/15 15:14:10 [notice] 24#24: signal 29 (SIGIO) received
nginx.1     | 2022/01/15 15:14:10 [notice] 24#24: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 32
nginx.1     | 2022/01/15 15:14:10 [notice] 24#24: worker process 32 exited with code 0
nginx.1     | 2022/01/15 15:14:10 [notice] 24#24: signal 29 (SIGIO) received
nginx.1     | 2022/01/15 15:14:10 [notice] 24#24: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 30
nginx.1     | 2022/01/15 15:14:10 [notice] 24#24: worker process 30 exited with code 0
nginx.1     | 2022/01/15 15:14:10 [notice] 24#24: signal 29 (SIGIO) received
nginx.1     | 2022/01/15 15:14:11 [notice] 31#31: exiting
```

I try with `chmod 775` for `/srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-9eac4f7c-81d6-48a7-9a4a-c8f20ceba7b5/nextcloud`, `/var/www` and `/var/lib/docker` reinstalation apache2 and installation php and effect is the same.